# How to search Contacts with address (FORMATTED_ADDRESS) with one query?

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

I try to implement a live search over the users contacts, and I want to get the name, thumbnail and address (if there is one) of each matching contact.

The live search is running while the user is typing.

So he types **ma** and will get 'martin', 'matthews'...

He'll continue with **mat** and will only see 'matthews'

I try to achieve this with a single query like the following, but I always get the contact number in the `FORMATTED_ADRESS` field. I guess I have a `JOIN` problem, because I'm using `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` and `ContactsContract.Contacts` in the same query?

```
public static List<ContactModel> getContactsForQuery(Context context, String query) {

    String[] projection = new String[] {
        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS
    };

    Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%" + query +  "%'";
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            String name = cursor.getString(0);
            String thumbail = cursor.getString(1);
            String formattedADress = cursor.getString(2);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

I actually solved my issue, with

1. querying for `Contacts._ID`, `Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME`
2. start a second query with the `Contacts._ID` like the following

   ```
   Cursor detailCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
          ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
          new String[]{
              CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.STREET,
              CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CITY,
              CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.POSTCODE
          },
          ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " 
              + CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.MIMETYPE + "=?",
          new String[]{
              String.valueOf(contactID),
              CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
          },
          null);
   ```

but this will start a second query for **every contact**, which might not be the best approach.

So my final question is: is it possible to get this work with the first query?

Comment: why downvote? did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh, very sad, that no one was able to answer my question and grab the bounty points ;-(

For the record, here's my working example. It solves the issue but I still think it's producing a big overload. On every user entry (`afterTextchange`) I call the `getContactsDetailsQuery` which first gets all users with their ID containing the query in their name (`cursor`) and afterwards I start another query (`detailCursor`) for every user to get the adress. To prevent the overload, i added an limit..

```
public static List<SearchModel> getContactDetailsForQuery(Context context, String query, int limit) {

    final int CONTACT_ID_INDEX = 0;
    final int CONTACT_NAME_INDEX = 1;
    final int CONTACT_THUMBNAIL_INDEX = 2;

    //my custom model to hold my results
    List<SearchModel> results = new ArrayList<SearchModel>();

    final String[] selectUser = new String[]{
        Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
        Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
    String selection = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%" + query + "%"};
    String sortOrder = Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, selectUser, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder, null);

    int contactCounter = 0;
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        do {
            String contactID = cursor.getString(CONTACT_ID_INDEX);
            String displayName = cursor.getString(CONTACT_NAME_INDEX);
            String thumbnail = cursor.getString(CONTACT_THUMBNAIL_INDEX);

            //get user details with user id (this is the query i wanted to change in my question!!)
            Cursor detailCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[]{
                    CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS},
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=? AND " +
                    CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.MIMETYPE + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactID), CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},
                null);

            if (detailCursor != null && detailCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                //special case: user has several address, query all of them
                do {
                    String formattedAddress = detailCursor.getString(detailCursor.getColumnIndex(CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS));
                    //user has serveral adress -> init model for each adress
                    SearchModel contact = new SearchModel();
                    results.add(contact);
                    contactCounter++;

                } while (detailCursor.moveToNext() && contactCounter < limit);

            } else {

                //user has no adress -> init model
                SearchModel contact = new SearchModel();
                results.add(contact);
                contactCounter++;
            }

            detailCursor.close();

        } while (cursor.moveToNext() && contactCounter < limit);
    }
    cursor.close();

    return results;
}
```